# Client-side Postgres Logging

Tags: postgresql, logging

I need to analyze Postgres queries generated by a web application. However, server-side logging is not enabled, and as it's a database used by many other developers I don't have permission to turn it on. For those familiar with MSSQL, a tool like SQL Profiler would be ideal, but my searches haven't found anything similar for Postgres. I'd certainly settle for something that creates a log file that I can examine.

Does anyone know a way to do this that doesn't involve straight-up debugging of the web app?

Thanks in advance!
-Steve

PS No Windows tools/solutions please, I'm running Linux and Mac OSX.

Comment: Check out the logging capabilities of the driver you are using (JDBC, ODBC, ...). You might also want to look into the [pg_stat_statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html) module (although that is server-side as well)

Comment: You can set up some kind of proxy between your app and Postgres, that will log all SQL before passing it to DB.

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Statement_Playback

Comment: What permissions do you have?  Do you have superuser access inside the database system?

Comment: I have superuser permissions, but not *permission*, if that makes sense. Any changes I'd make to the postgres server would have to be run by higher-ups with a pretty long lead time. I'm leaning towards using a proxy as mentioned by Igor and Pavel.

Answer (score 1):

If you have superuser access in the database system, you can run

```
SET log_statements = all;
SET client_min_messages = log;
```

and see the statement log on the client side.